# My javascript regex code does not work for mobile view

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, wpforms

I used the following code in WPforms on Wordpress to only allow english characters, numbers and space char in my form. Everything works great until you try it from mobile (the same website and same form, Chrome on Android for example), it just does not work and allows you to fill out any character to the fields.. is there any way to prevent it? I mean to make it work for mobile and don't allow visitors to put special characters from mobile too?

```
function wpf_dev_char_restrict() {
?>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
     
    jQuery(function($){
        $( '.wpf-char-restrict' ).on( 'keypress', function(e){
             
            var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$');
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
             
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                alert ( "Please fill out the form in English. Thank you!" ); // Put any message here
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
         
        //Prevent any copy and paste features to by-pass the restrictions
        $( '.wpf-char-restrict' ).bind( 'copy paste', function (e) {
             
            var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+$');
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
             
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                alert ( "Pasting feature has been disabled for this field" ); // Put any message here
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
         
    });
 
</script>
 
<?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_dev_char_restrict', 10 );
```

Comment: please try `keydown` instead of `keypress`

Comment: copy and paste events don't provide a key code; they're not keyboard events

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input` event. This event will fire whatever the input method is: keyboard, mouse drag/drop, context menu, clipboard, other device.

This event triggers when the input has already changed, so you'd need to keep track of the value as it was before the latest modification:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    var accepted = "";
    $( '.wpf-char-restrict' ).on( 'input', function() {
        var regex = /^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i;
        if (!regex.test($(this).val())) {
            alert ( "Please fill out the form in English. Thank you!" );
            $(this).val(accepted); 
        } else {
            accepted = $(this).val();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="wpf-char-restrict">
```

NB: You may want to allow for some punctuation in the input (like comma, point, ...etc).

Comment: On things like "copy" and "paste", it's probably the case that the event object won't have "which" or "keyCode". Testing the element value is the right thing to do.

Comment: when I tried this code, it does not even work on desktop anymore :-D

Comment: I turned it into a runnable snippet, and it works for me (run it). Also on mobile. If it doesn't work for you, there must be other code that is interfering?